# Queen's Gambit Accepted : how should White continue after 3.e3 Be6?

Tags: opening, queens-gambit-accepted

The [Wikipedia article on Queen's Gambit Accepted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen%27s_Gambit_Accepted#3.e3) simply notes that "... White has good compensation after 4.Ne2".

```
  [FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 dxc4 3.e3 Be6 4. Ne2 (4.Qc2)
```

What about Qc2 to add further pressure to the c4 black pawn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Queen's Gambit Accepted : how should White continue after 3.e3 Be6?

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 dxc4 3.e3 Be6 4. Na3!?
```

seems good to me-Black would not be able to hold the `c4` pawn. I would take `c4` pawn with the knight and head for `e5`. The other knight can bolster him from `f3` and there will always be threats to `f7` or to Blacks light squared bishop with `Ng5`.

> The Wikipedia article on Queen's Gambit Accepted simply notes that "... White has good compensation after 4.Ne2".

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 dxc4 3.e3 Be6 4. Ne2 b5? 5.a4! c6 ( 5...a6 6.axb5 ) ( 5...bxa4 6.Nf4 Bd5 7.Nc3 c6 8.e4! ) 6.axb5! cxb5 7.Nec3!! Bd7 ( 7...Qd7 8.Qf3 Nc6! 9.Nxb5! ( 9.d5?-+ Nb4 10.dxe6 Nc2+ 11.Ke2 Qd3#) Bf5 10.Nd2 Bd3 11.Nxc4+- ) 8.Qf3 Bc6 9.d5 Bd7 10.b3! Qc8 ( 10...b4 11.Bxc4!! bxc3? 12.d6!+- Bc6 13.Qxf7+ Kd7 14.Qe6+! Ke8 15. d7+! Qxd7 16.Qf7+ Kd8 17.Qxf8++-) 11.bxc4 b4 ( 11...bxc4 12.Na3 ) 12.Na4 Bxa4 13.Rxa4 a5
```

I bet that strong engine can find even better compensation for White than one I provided above, but I also think that my lines are sufficient as well.

> What about Qc2 to add further pressure to the c4 black pawn?

It should work, but you will **needlessly** complicate matters too much.

Hopefully this answer is what you were looking for.

If you have further questions leave a comment.

Best regards.